# An issue when using trunc function

Tags: r

i have an issue when i using this function in R. I don't know why `trunc(z)` is 637 instead of 638 as `x = 51/80*100`.

```
x <- 51/80*100
x
#[1] 63.75

z = abs(x)*10^1
z = z + 0.5
z
#[1] 638
z = trunc(z)
z
#[1] 637
z = z/10^1
z
#[1] 63.7
```

Answer (score 0):

As @d.b already pointed out that `z` is numeric and with numerics you don't necessarily have what you see.

Check

```
formatC(z, digits = 14, format = "f")
#[1] "637.99999999999989"
```

(You might have to change `digits` argument on your system)

Also if you convert it to integer, you get

```
as.integer(z)
#[1] 637
```

You can `round` the numeric before using them

```
trunc(round(z))
#[1] 638
```